# How to perform dynamic unmarsahlling

Tags: go, unmarshalling

Can anyone help me perform dynamic unmarshalling depending on the type of messages received from a diameter client. In the code below, I have to two structures which represent two different messages received by a diameter server. I would like to modify the current code which unmarshals the request to the struct `var req HandleDERRequest` such that the unmarshalling is done dynamically either to the `var req HandleDERRequest` or `var challreq HandleChallRequest`, depending on the received message that matches a particular structure. I have tried to implement with the code below but it not working as it should. All the answers are being return at the same time and this is not what am expecting.

```
func HandleDER(settings sm.Settings) diam.HandlerFunc {

    // If received AVP messages are of this struct format, Unmarshal message to this structure

    type HandleDERRequest struct {
        SessionID         datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"Session-Id"`
        OriginHost        datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Host"`
        OriginRealm       datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Realm"`
        DestinationHost   datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Host"`
        DestinationRealm  datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Realm"`
        UserName          datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"User-Name"`
        AuthSessionState  datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"Auth-Session-State"`
        AuthApplicationID datatype.Unsigned32       `avp:"Auth-Application-Id"`
        AuthRequestType   datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"Auth-Request-Type"`
        EAPPayload        datatype.OctetString      `avp:"EAP-Payload"`
        RATType           datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"RAT-Type"`
        ANID              datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"ANID"`
    }

    // If received AVP messages are of this struct format, Unmarshal message to this structure

    type HandleChallRequest struct {
        SessionID        datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"Session-Id"`
        OriginHost       datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Host"`
        OriginRealm      datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Realm"`
        DestinationHost  datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Host"`
        DestinationRealm datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Realm"`
        EAPPayload       datatype.OctetString      `avp:"EAP-Payload"`
    }

    return func(c diam.Conn, m *diam.Message) {

        var err error = nil
        var req HandleDERRequest

        var code uint32 = diam.Success
        err = m.Unmarshal(&req)
        if err != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unmarshal failed: %s", err)
            code = diam.UnableToComply
            log.Printf("Invalid DER(%d): %s\n", code, err.Error())
        }
        a := m.Answer(code)
        a.NewAVP(avp.SessionID, avp.Mbit, 0, req.SessionID)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginHost, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationHost)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginRealm, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationRealm)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginStateID, avp.Mbit, 0, settings.OriginStateID)
        _, err = AKA_Challenge_Request(settings, c, a)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send AAA challenge request: %s", err.Error())
        }

        var challreq HandleChallageRequest
        err = m.Unmarshal(&challreq)
        if err != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unmarshal failed: %s", err)
            code = diam.UnableToComply
            log.Printf("Invalid DER(%d): %s\n", code, err.Error())
        }
        a = m.Answer(code)
        a.NewAVP(avp.SessionID, avp.Mbit, 0, req.SessionID)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginHost, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationHost)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginRealm, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationRealm)
        a.NewAVP(avp.OriginStateID, avp.Mbit, 0, settings.OriginStateID)
        _, err = AKA_Success_Notification(settings, c, a)
        if err != nil {
           log.Printf("Failed to send Success Notification: %s", err.Error())
       }
    }
}
```

```
func AKA_Challenge_Request(settings sm.Settings, w io.Writer, m *diam.Message) (n int64, err error) {
    PayloadSlice := []byte(`RAND, AUTHN, MAC, RESULT_ID`)
    m.NewAVP(avp.EAPPayload, avp.Mbit, 0, datatype.OctetString(PayloadSlice))
    return m.WriteTo(w)
}

func AKA_Success_Notification(settings sm.Settings, w io.Writer, m *diam.Message) (n int64, err error) {
    EAPSlice := []byte(`EAP_Success`)
    MSKSlice := []byte(`EAP-Master-Session-Key`)
    m.NewAVP(avp.EAPPayload, avp.Mbit, 0, datatype.OctetString(EAPSlice))
    m.NewAVP(avp.EAPMasterSessionKey, avp.Mbit, 0, datatype.OctetString(MSKSlice))
    return m.WriteTo(w)
}
```

I know there should be an if condition of the return function but I don't know how to start. Please any idea about how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no need for the HandleChallRequest type at this point. If I have read the fields correctly both types have the same base attributes but the HandleDERRequest type has more, can these not just be nil values in the unmarshalled type ?

You could then either do some kind of nil check to ascertain one data set from the other, or more preferred would be create an interface that has all the fields and a common set of methods so that you can then create two types that implement this interface and the choice becomes which one to create.

**Edit 1.**

Sorry again if I am missing the point but I still don't see the need for the different types, it seems to me that they are just data containers, with different data.

Here is what I was thinking in terms of a single data type.

```
func HandleDER(settings sm.Settings) diam.HandlerFunc {

// If received AVP messages are of this struct format, Unmarshal message to this structure

type HandleRequest struct {
    SessionID         datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"Session-Id"`
    OriginHost        datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Host"`
    OriginRealm       datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Origin-Realm"`
    DestinationHost   datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Host"`
    DestinationRealm  datatype.DiameterIdentity `avp:"Destination-Realm"`
    UserName          datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"User-Name"`
    AuthSessionState  datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"Auth-Session-State"`
    AuthApplicationID datatype.Unsigned32       `avp:"Auth-Application-Id"`
    AuthRequestType   datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"Auth-Request-Type"`
    EAPPayload        datatype.OctetString      `avp:"EAP-Payload"`
    RATType           datatype.Enumerated       `avp:"RAT-Type"`
    ANID              datatype.UTF8String       `avp:"ANID"`
}

// If received AVP messages are of this struct format, Unmarshal message to this structure

return func(c diam.Conn, m *diam.Message) {

    var err error = nil
    var req HandleRequest

    var code uint32 = diam.Success

    err = m.Unmarshal(&req)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Unmarshal failed: %s", err)
        code = diam.UnableToComply
        log.Printf("Invalid DER(%d): %s\n", code, err.Error())
    }
    a := m.Answer(code)
    a.NewAVP(avp.SessionID, avp.Mbit, 0, req.SessionID)
    a.NewAVP(avp.OriginHost, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationHost)
    a.NewAVP(avp.OriginRealm, avp.Mbit, 0, req.DestinationRealm)
    a.NewAVP(avp.OriginStateID, avp.Mbit, 0, settings.OriginStateID)

    if ("messagetype" == "first message type") {
        _, err = AKA_Challenge_Request(settings, c, a)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send AAA challenge request: %s", err.Error())
        }
    } else {
        _, err = AKA_Success_Notification(settings, c, a)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to send Success Notification: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes you are right, they all have the same base attributes but the message content of the AKA_Challenge_Request and the AKA_Success_Notification are different. These different messages will have to be returned based on the message type received matching the specific type. I have added the AKA_Challenge_Request and the AKA_Success_Notification functions to the code.